# Regular expression to accept missing word

Tags: regex, expression

I am trying to write a regexp that matches a sentence. Here are the three sentences I want to match

```
1) Volume High. My Example
2) Volume Low. My Example
3) Volume. My Example
```

I do not now how to represent the missing word in the following regexp

```
^Volume\s(High|Low|)\.\sMy Example$
```

The regexp above only matches sentence 1 and 2, but not 3. How can I make it work?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You want to precede `\s` with the `*` operator meaning "zero or more" times and use an [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) group.

```
^Volume\s*(High|Low)?\.\s*My Example$
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eJ1qC4/1)

Comment: Is the OP's suggested `High` OR `Low` OR (nothing) not a valid regex? (Rather ... it *seems* valid, as it does work, but the last OR is then silently ignored.)

Comment: hwnd's answer works. It also works, If I add ^Volume\s*(High|Low|) to what I tried before. Thank you all

Comment: @Jongware I see what you're saying but to me it looked like a typo perhaps.

Comment: @hwnd: the OP must have thought it matches 'an empty string' .. and lo! it does! See my answer :-)

Comment: the 0 or 1 operator, `?`, is all the OP's regex needed, as Jongware pointed out. `?` is probably a better choice than `*` since you could match hundreds of spaces with `*`.

Answer (score 1):

To make a token in a regex optional (occurring 0 or 1 times), you add a `?` after it.

The High and Low keywords are already grouped into one token, so `(High|Low)` would make them optional, but the space before would still be required.

You therefore have to choose either to make the space optional even if the next word matches...

```
^Volume\s?(High|Low)?\.\sMy Example$
```

...or create an extra group with the space in, so that the whole group can be optional...

```
^Volume(\s(High|Low|))?\.\sMy Example$
```

If you're capturing the value of the High|Low group, adding an extra group may be annoying; many regex implementations allow you to make a "non-capturing group" by adding `?:` at the beginning, like this:

```
^Volume(?:\s(High|Low|))?\.\sMy Example$
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggested

```
^Volume\s(High|Low|)\.\sMy Example$
```

does not work on

```
Volume. My Example
```

because there is no space before the period, and the expression asks for it. Moving the space into the expression makes it work:

```
^Volume(\sHigh|\sLow|)\.\sMy Example$
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. I see what you mean
I ended up using the following

```
^Volume\s*(High|Low|)\.\sMy Example$
```

I like it because it is simpler. 
Thank you all for your help.